# Questions about props in movies

Tags: discussion

I asked [a question that marked as trivial](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/17072).  I wanted to know if these kinds of goggles actually existed. In all my experience, they do not.  After I did some Googling, I came across a few bad Ask Yahoo! Answers pages.  I figured that I could get [a higher quality response](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/17081) from movies.  If I worded the question incorrectly, could somebody assist me in wording it better.  If this is not the appropriate place for this type of question, then would somebody be able to assist me to another forum that is as high quality as the StackExchange sites?

Comment: For me the key thing is .... will the answer be of general interest to someone interested in the movie.  A model number of some goggles is unlikely to be interesting, whether its feasible *at all* is interesting.  The edit which added this swung me behind the question.

Answer (score 3):

Being one of the close voters of the original question, I should add my views here. Before the rewording, the question read as if you just wanted to know the brand of some completely irrelevant prop used in the movie, which could be regarded trivia. Things like *"what car model did [actor] drive in [movie]?"* without any other explanations don't really add anything to the understanding or apreceation of the movie.

But I also agree that it is sometimes hard to define what exactly is trivia and what is not and that it is more or less up to the community to decide if the question gets closed or not (which it did in this case). But this question is also a good example for a question that got reopened after improvement (again entirely by the decision of the community). And in fact by employing the angle of *"was this real, does such a thing exist?"* (and thus asking what you *actually* wanted to know) you give a much better reason for the question (and got quite a good answer for that).

As a last word, it is never a bad idea to give as much information and reasons in your question as possible to help the others understand your problem and provide a good answer.